# Is this a bijective function for $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (-2,5)$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (-2,5)$

I'm basically trying to prove the two intervals above have the same cardinality by finding a bijective function.  I'm not sure I did it properly but the function I found was:

$y=-2x+1$

It satisfies both intervals, but is this a bijective function?  It seems to be both surjective and injective.

Comment: Given the domain of $(0, 1)$, this function has the range of $(y(1), y(0))=(-1,1)$, so it is not surjective.

Comment: You want $f(0)=-2$ and you want $f(1)=5$.  If it were linear and monotonic increasing, that would be convenient as well.  What function does that?

Comment: You want a function which appropriately scales the interval, and then shifts it. This method can be used to define a bijection between any two given (finite) open intervals.

Comment: An injective function is strictly monotone. Your line is injective but now you need it will be surjective. Solve the equation $y=ax+b$ with the two points $\langle 0,-2\rangle$ and $\langle 1,5\rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the domain of $(0, 1)$, this function has the range of $(y(1), y(0))=(-1, 1)$, so it is not surjective. [@KushalBhuyan's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1823927/307483) answer can help better understand this.

To map $(0, 1)$ to $(-2, 5)$, you need to map $0$ to $-2$ and $1$ to $5$. Thus, we have $(x_1,y_1)=(0,-2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(1,5)$. Solve using point-slope form.

Comment: Using your method I still get the linear equation I originally had.  So I must be doing something wrong

Comment: The slope is change in $y$ over change in $y$, or $\frac{5-(-2)}{1-0}=7$. Using point-slope with $m=7$ and $(x_1,y_1)=(0,-2)$, we get $y-(-2)=7(x-0)$. Solve for $y$.

Comment: Thanks so much, I totally understand what I was doing wrong now!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** For onto ness what is the preimage of $3$? Is there any?

In short your function is not onto. For bijectiveness a function should satisfy both one-one and ontoness.

Comment: $-1$ is the preimage of 3

Comment: @free_mind However, $-1$ is not in the domain of $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Which function $f(x)=ax+b$ satisfies $f(0)=-2$, $f(1)=5$? Is it for this $a$ strictly increasing?